# PHP not encoding to JSON

Tags: php, json, xamarin

This may seem like a duplicate, but I have tried other answers to no avail. I'm using Xamarin and PHP. My PHP query works, but it is not returning properly formated PHP. I'm using PHP 5.6 and JSON is checked. My PHP is:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT id,user,water,poop FROM dailyMisc WHERE user = ? AND misc_day = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('is',$userId,$dateSelected);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($idR,$user_idR,$waterR,$poopR);
$stmt->store_result();

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $misc[] = array('Id'=>$idR,'UserId'=>$user_idR,'Water'=>$waterR,'Poop'=>$poopR);
        echo json_encode($misc);
    }
```

PHP returns:

> [{"Id":25,"UserId":24,"Water":0,"Poop":1}]

My Xamarin error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'BitesBoardMobile.businessObject.BusinessMisc' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: Change `$misc[]` to `$misc`. Also, if you want multiple values, then I recommend declaring `$misc` before the while (`$misc = array();`), then using `array_push($misc, array('Id'=>...=>$poopR);` you can fill up the array with arrays (if you are not sure about the while loop's iteration count) Also, if you're doing that, you have to echo `$misc` after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to have all the information you need: *the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})*. You're trying to pass a JSON *Array* into a function that's expecting a JSON object.

> php returns [{"Id":25,"UserId":24,"Water":0,"Poop":1}]

Those square brackets indicate you're sending an array, not an object. An object would look like this (notice no square brackets):

```
{"Id":25,"UserId":24,"Water":0,"Poop":1}
```

Luckily, the object you want is also the first and only member of the array, so you can either take that (probably `json_encode($misc[0])`) or cast `$misc` as an object in the first place, by taking the brackets off of its declaration (`$misc =`, not `$misc[] =`):

```
 $misc = array('Id'=>$idR,'UserId'=>$user_idR,'Water'=>$waterR,'Poop'=>$poopR);
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that your array was not properly formatted.

```
$misc = ['Id'=>$idR,'UserId'=>$user_idR,'Water'=>$waterR,'Poop'=>$poopR];
echo json_encode($misc);
```